# regex to match the end of string doesn't work

Tags: regex, typescript

I want to recognize the house number in a given string. Here you can find some sample inputs:

```
"My house number is 23"
"23"
"23a"
"23 a"
"The house number is 23 a and the street ist XY"
"The house number is 23 a"
```

I have the following `regex`:

```
\d+(([\s]{0,1}[a-zA-Z]{0,1}[\s])*|[\s]{0,1}[a-zA-Z]{0,1}$)
```

But it is not able to capture the inputs which have the number followed by a letter at the end of the line (e.g. `the house number is 23 a`).

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I finally need the `regex` in `typescript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your problem correctly, this should work:

```
   (\d+(\s?[a-zA-Z]?\s?|\s?[a-zA-Z]$))
```

Note: `[\s]{0,1}` is the same as `\s?`

https://regex101.com/r/r6WHFy/1

The issue in your regex was that `The house number is 23 a` matches `([\s]{0,1}[a-zA-Z]{0,1}[\s])*` part, thus the parser "does not need" to look for the part with end of string symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write the pattern using word boundaries and without using an alternation `|`

```
\b\d+(?:\s*[a-zA-Z])?\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\s*[a-zA-Z])?` Optionally match optional whitespace chars and a-zA-Z
- `\b` A word boundary

```js
const regex = /\b\d+(?:\s*[a-zA-Z])?\b/;

[
  "My house number is 23",
  "23",
  "23a",
  "23 a",
  "The house number is 23 a and the street ist XY",
  "The house number is 23 a"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(regex)[0]));
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c7zFEb/1)